# Cubic function: Cardano's method

Tags: numerical-methods, orthogonal-polynomials, cubics

([Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_nature_of_the_roots))

So I am writing an essay on different ways to solve cubics. 
But I get stuck in the Cardano's method...

Mainly is the part with Cardano's method's condition $\frac{q^2}{4} + \frac{p^3}{27}$ must be bigger than $0.$

What if the condition was not true?

What if the condition was $0$ or negative?

What would happen? Would that make the method more complicated ?

Also, what are the pros and cons, or limitations of this method.

Comment: This is explained in your link, via the choice of $u^3$. In Cardano's time, complex numbers had not been invented.

Comment: It is really explained earlier in that Wikipedia article, since the Tschirnhaus transformations do not change the discriminant. If the discriminant is $0$, there is a repeated root. If the discriminant is $<0$, then there is one real root and two complex conjugate non-real roots. The formula for the roots is still valid if properly interpreted.

Comment: see here http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+ax%5E3%2Bbx%5E2%2Bcx%2Bd%3D0&lk=4&num=1

Comment: HI, thank for the reply. However, in the wiki page, u^3 is the + conjugate pair, but when the discriminant is <0, u becomes - conjugate pair. I am sorry i cant explain it well here, but is there an error in the wiki page, the +/- sign. I dont mean to be pompous but I want to make sure what I am learning is correct. :)

Comment: You can work it out for yourself via elementary calculus. Consider $x^{3}+px+q$ with $p,q$ real. If this has more than one real root, and no repeated roots, then there must be three real roots, and the derivative must vanish twice on the real line  by Rolle's theorem. Hence we must have $3x^{2} + p = 0$ for some real $x$ and $p < 0$. Also, the cubic takes negative values for $x <<0$ and positive values for $x >>0$, so consider the local maxima and minima. If there is a repeated root, then that is a root of the derivative, so $\sqrt{\frac{-p}{3}}$ must be a root of the cubic.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}$ need not be bigger than $0$.  If it is less than $0$, it has no square root in the real numbers, but it has a square root in the *complex numbers*.  Do you know about those?

Historically, the complex numbers were invented for precisely this reason.  The fascinating thing about cubics is that even when a cubic has real coefficients and all three roots are real, you might still need to introduce complex numbers to give a solution by radicals.

Comment: But one you have the solutions in radicals, you can still simplify it and get rid of the radicals right ? I have done a question before and it has 3 real roots and they can be expressed without the use of radicals.... I am not sure... sorry if it seems childish for you. ;(I am still doing my high school diploma, but have to do a long essay that uses maths above high school level.... Thanks :)

Comment: @TommyLassa Good question, and the surprising answer is that you can't in general.  For some examples, such as what you get from expanding out $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$, say, you have nice rational solutions, but in certain cases (look up *casus irreducibilis*), it is impossible to get a closed-form radical expression for the solutions of a cubic without moving outside the real numbers *even when the coefficients of the cubic and all three of its roots are real*.